# How to stop OSX messages app storing every sent SMS?

Tags: applescript, message

I have written a simple applescript script to go through a list of phone numbers and send an SMS using Messages app on OSX. This all works great but Messages stores every sent message and I don't want it to do that. I've unchecked the only option in Messages preferences to not save the messages on exit but this seems to do nothing. It still saves the messages.

I don't mind adding to my apple script to 'tell' messages to delete the messages but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to delete the individual messages or the whole conversation with your contacts?

Comment: Delete the whole conversation for that buddy.